# How can I reject mail in postfix with a blank return path?

Tags: postfix, email-server

Been getting spam emails where the Return-Path is equal to "Return-Path: <>", how can I go ahead and block these emails. Also is there an option that could be added in policyd-spf.conf to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure those mails don't originate on the server itself? For instance, this is how DSNs look like. Could you please provide the full log line which contains such an address, and other corresponding lines with the same queue ID?

Comment: https://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html